# Can't find nodes in node editor

Tags: node-editor, interface, shader-nodes

I'm new to blender so forgive me for the noob question.
I created a new material, but can't find it in the node editor, I tried to follow instruction from other posts in this forum but haven't found a solution.

Can you please help me?
[image]

Answer (score 7):

The problem why you don't have any nodes in your material is because you are not in shader editor but rather you are in Geometry node editor:

[image]

Change it to shader editor and you will see your material nodes.